# creating form error with symfony

Tags: symfony

i was trying to create a form , using form builder,but i got an error , and i'm trying to solve it but i can't find the problem. 
Any one have an idea why i have this error :

```
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in C:....\SearchFilmForm.php line 13
here is my code 

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('titre')
           ->add('motcle', 'text', array('label' => 'Mot-clé'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `;` after `->add('titre');`